Is it possible to embed Gazebo in Tkinter GUI?
I am creating my own GUI using Tkinter in Python. I want to embed the Gazebo window in a frame of my GUI, it is possible?
I have tried with this example:
command = ["wmctrl", "-i", "-r", gazebo_window_id, "-e", "0,{},{},{},{}".format(self.master.winfo_x(), self.master.winfo_y(), 600, 400)]

Nothing changes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
